# Concat all angular2 dependencies to one file

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, systemjs

I'm trying to use gulp to package all my vendor dependencies into one big vendor.js  file.
So far I have use gulp-concat to make it into one file, however it doesn't load the system.js included files properly.
Meaning when i'm trying to bootstrap the angular app, systemjs goes out and fetches two files, @angular/platform-browser-dynamic and @angular/core, however these are both included in the vendor.js, and will therefore not be found.
Normally the angular files would be loaded from the node_modules folder, however that is as far as I know a very bad idea in production, and because this application is served out of a public folder my a static file server middleware in my application, including node_modules in the destribution seems a really bad idea to me.
Using other answers from around SO has gotten me this gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    path = require('path'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    project = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json'),
    nodesource = "node_modules/",
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    jspm = require('gulp-jspm-build'),
    input = {
        sass: [
            'frontend/sass/**/*.scss'
        ],

        typescript: [
            'typings/index.d.ts',
            'frontend/ts/**/*.ts'
        ],

        body: [
            'frontend/html/**/*.html'
        ],

        vendor: [
            nodesource + 'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            nodesource + 'zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            nodesource + 'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            nodesource + 'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            nodesource + 'rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js',
            nodesource + '@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            nodesource + '@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            nodesource + '@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            nodesource + '@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            nodesource + '@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            nodesource + '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            './systemjs.config.js'
        ]
    },
    outputDir = './public';


gulp.task('compile:ts', function() {
    return gulp.src(input.typescript)
        .pipe(ts(project))
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir))
});

gulp.task('bundle-vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src(input.vendor)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir));
});

gulp.task('copy-html', function () {
    return gulp.src(input.body)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compile:ts', 'bundle-vendor', 'copy-html'], function(){});
```

This systemjs.config.js file:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: "/",
    map: {
        'app': 'app.js'
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

This makes my typescript files into one app.js files, which is put in my public folder, however the vendor.js files doesn't act like it has the dependences my project needs.

I'm guessing i'm packing the wrong angular files, however i'm not quite sure what files should otherwise be fetched, and how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are having `gulpfile.js`, `public` folder and `system.config.js` under your root directory, try removing `./`.

```
project = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json'),  //<-- removed ./

'systemjs.config.js' //<-- removed ./

 outputDir = 'public';  //<-- removed ./
```

see if this helps.

edit :

try loading this instead:

```
        nodesource + 'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        nodesource + 'zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        nodesource + 'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        nodesource + 'systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
        nodesource + '@angular/**/*.*',
        nodesource + 'rxjs/**/*.*'
        nodesource + 'angular2-in-memory-web-api/**/*.*',
        './systemjs.config.js'
```

Comment: systemjs.config.js are added to the vendor.js as intended, it is just not loading the dependencies correctly.

Comment: While that might even have a chance of working i'm just going to not do that, as that will make the vendor.js file 20 MB, which really isn't something I would want to be serving my clients either.